# Javascript nested array with nested loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I created a nested array as I could so far but I feel like i did it wrong or something does not make sense. Could anyone please have a look and tell me if my array is the way to build nested array. All I want is to create rows under specific title, so I nested data and calling it with nested loops. Maybe theres is a simpler way of achiving it. Here is the code:

```
var data = [

    {title:'Row Title 1'},

    [{leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'},
    {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'},
    {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'}],

    {title:'Row Title 2'},

    [{leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'},
    {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'},
    {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'}]

    ];

    for (var i=0, j=data.length; i < j; i++) {

        if(data[i].title != null){
            document.write('<b>'+data[i].title+'</b><br />');
        }

        for(p=0,plen=data[i].length; p<plen;p++){
            document.write('<p style="background:#eee;">'+data[i][p].leftCol+'</p>');
            document.write('<p>'+data[i][p].rightCol+'</p>');       
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any particular reason you chose to use an array and not JSON?

Comment: No reason. But My code is crushing my mobile application and I feel like i am doing something wrong with my array because if I take away titles "{title:'Row Title 1'}" then it works perfectly.

Comment: The reason your code breaks is because your nested for loop is not conditional (it checks for the length property on objects `{title: 'Row Title 1'}` and `{title: 'Row Title 2'}`). Wrap it in an `else` scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you're using should be more like this:

```
var data = [

    {title:'Row Title 1', contents: [

      {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'},
      {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'},
      {leftCol:'Some text for left column',rightCol:'Some text for right column'}

    ],

    // ...
];
```

That way, each row is an object with a "title" attribute and a "contents" attribute.  Your loop would then look like this:

```
for (var i=0, j=data.length; i < j; i++) {

    if(data[i].title != null){
        document.write('<b>'+data[i].title+'</b><br />');
    }

    for(var p=0, plen=data[i].contents.length; p < plen; p++){
        document.write('<p style="background:#eee;">'+data[i].contents[p].leftCol+'</p>');
        document.write('<p>'+data[i].contents[p].rightCol+'</p>');       
    }
}
```

Comment: The structure of the data really doesn't matter as long as the algorithm you use to retrieve it does so properly. Then again, it's always a good practice to structure your data logically. So +1! ;)

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is true. If it were necessary that the structure be as in the OP, it would be possible to deal with that in JavaScript, but personally I like fixing problems as closely as possible to where the problem starts :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your code more robust follow these guidelines:

1. It's always better to initialize for loops like so if you have a length: `for (var i = 0, l = length; l--; i++)`. The reason for this syntax is explained in fuller detail by [Nicholas C. Zakas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU).
2. Always store variables accessed multiple times in a local variable. It speeds up execution (e.g. `idata = data[i];`).
3. Avoid duck typing as far as possible (e.g. `data[i].title != null`). Check for the type of the variable first. It's slower, but the code is easier to understand and maintain. Try the `typeOf` function at the bottom of the post (e.g. `typeOf(idata) === "Object"`).
4. It's usually always better to use `===` instead of `==` and `!==` instead of `!=` because they don't perform type coercion which might lead to unexpected results.
5. Instead of creating multiple inline styles, create a single class `.greyBackground { background-color: #EEEEEE; }` and set the `className` of each `leftCol` paragraph to `greyBackground`.
6. Avoid using `document.write`. It's slow, causes reflow of the document, and halts loading assets while the page is downloading. The best way to create dynamic content using JavaScript is to use the `document.createDocumentFragment` method as I'll explain below.
7. It's always better to create nodes in JavaScript yourself. If you use a string in `document.write` or `element.innerHTML` then the browser parses the string and converts it into the nodes anyway. Thus using that method is slower.

This is how I would have written your JavaScript:

```
var data = [
    "Row Title 1",
    {
        "leftCol": "Some text for left column",
        "rightCol": "Some text for right column"
    }, {
        "leftCol": "Some text for left column",
        "rightCol": "Some text for right column"
    }, {
        "leftCol": "Some text for left column",
        "rightCol": "Some text for right column"
    },
    "Row Title 2",
    {
        "leftCol": "Some text for left column",
        "rightCol": "Some text for right column"
    }, {
        "leftCol": "Some text for left column",
        "rightCol": "Some text for right column"
    }, {
        "leftCol": "Some text for left column",
        "rightCol": "Some text for right column"
    }
];

function typeOf(value) {
    if (value === null) {
        return "null";
    } else if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return "undefined";
    } else {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
    }
}

var element;
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var idata;

for (var i = 0, l = data.length; l--; i++) {
    idata = data[i];
    if (typeOf(idata) === "Object") {
        element = document.createElement("p");
        element.className = "greyBackground";
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(idata.leftCol));
        fragment.appendChild(element);

        element = document.createElement("p");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(idata.rightCol));
        fragment.appendChild(element);
    } else {
        element = document.createElement("b");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(idata));
        fragment.appendChild(element);

        element = document.createElement("br");
        fragment.appendChild(element);
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Test my page and yours. In all probability mine will execute faster. If you have any doubts feel free to ask me. Cheers! =)